# Android activity transition from bottom to top and top to bottom black background issue

Tags: android, android-transitions

MainActivity with the navigation drawer, tabLayout and viewPager with three fragments.

Click on the fragment button, needs to invoke another activity. It needs the transition from "bottom to top" and when it back to main activity, it needs "top to bottom" transition.

This is the main activity UI.

[image]

[image]

Above is the transition from bottom to top. I capture the screeshot during transition. I highlight with the red box. This is the issue. I see the black area.

My AppTheme is like that

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatAlertDialogStyle</item>
</style>
```

But I don't want to see the black area in the transition, how to solve it. 
If needs to change to fragment, then I have another post with fragment, they have another more issues.
bottom_to_top_enter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="3000"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

Bottom_to_top_exit

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="3000"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="-100%" />
</set>
```

top_to_bottom_enter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="3000"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="-100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

top_to_bottom_exit

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="3000"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="100%" />
</set>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: set  <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item> in theme

Comment: @DivyeshPatel, I added to my AppTheme, it still the same with black screen above the toolbar and the activity background becomes black also. But i want the activity background white.

Comment: set white color in windowBackground

Comment: @DivyeshPatel, try it and still result what i show in the above. The same. During transition, still black appear during transition.

Comment: I solved it by giving it another transparent theme.

Answer (score 1):

> Try this :
>
> Create anim folder inside your res folder and copy this four files :

**slide_in_bottom.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromYDelta="100%p"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
```

**slide_out_bottom.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromYDelta="0" 
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
```

**slide_in_top.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:toYDelta="0%p"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
```

**slide_out_top.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:toYDelta="100%p"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
```

**call this after calling start activity**

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_bottom, R.anim.slide_out_bottom);
```

**or**

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_top, R.anim.slide_out_top);
```

Comment: yeah, i call this overridePendingTransition. 
My animation slide in top bottom, i think will be the same. I update in my post.

Comment: i post in another answer with your animation file. Still see black screen.

Comment: I solved it by giving it another transparent theme to the second activity. No more see the black screen during animation. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

@Aniruddh Parihar, the black gap becomes a bit smaller. But still have...

[image]